# catching an event in VBScript

Tags: dom, scripting, vbscript

guys. This is a VBS script that opens google, fills a form, and clicks a search button.

```
set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.navigate("www.google.com")

ie.visible = true

while ie.readystate <> 4
    wscript.sleep 100
WEnd

set fields = ie.document.getelementsbyname("q")
set buttons = ie.document.getelementsbyname("btnG")

fields(0).value = "some query"
buttons(0).click

ie.quit

Sub OnClickSub()
    MsgBox  "button clicked!", 0
End Sub
```

Obviously, `buttons(0).click` fires an onclick event of the button, which I somehow need to catch in my script, and provide it with some processing like launching `OnClickSub()`.

Has anyone got any ideas how this should be done?

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to attach a VBS Function/Sub to the click event of a button in a web page, I believe the best you can do is invoke whatever is attached to the click of that button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`GetRef`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekabbe10.aspx) function to obtain a pointer to your event handler and bind it to the [`onclick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536913.aspx) event, like this:

```
buttons(0).onclick = GetRef("OnClickSub")
```

(Apparently, [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343.aspx) doesn't work when called from outside the web page.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple way to catch events that happen in Excel. Excel must be open for this to work. Copy and paste this into a new VBScript, and run it. Then go into Excel, and change a cell's value. A Message Box will pop up showing you which cell you changed.

```
'/////////////////////////////////////////////////Event Constant Definitions/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    EVENT_CELL_CHANGE = 1   '//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    EVENT_SELECTED_CELL_CHANGE = 2 '/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    EVENT_SELECTED_SHEET_CHANGE = 3 '///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    EVENT_SELECTED_WORKBOOK_CHANGE = 4 '///////////////////////////////////////
'/////////////////////////////////////////////////Event Constant Definitions/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'_______________________________________________________________________
'/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'////////////////////////////////////////////////////Global Program/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
set O = getObject( , "Excel.Application")
Call WaitUntil_Event(EVENT_CELL_CHANGE, O.Selection, RtnVar, "BLANK")
msgbox RtnVar.address

'/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'////////////////////////////////////////////End of Global Program//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'_______________________________________________________________________
'/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'///////////////////////////////////////////Start of Main Sub Program/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'///////////////////////////////////////////This program was written by///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'///////////////////////////////////////////Ben Ahrens (April 5th, 2019///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Sub WaitUntil_Event(EventType, CheckVal, ByRef ReturnVariable, RunVBScript_FileName)
    On Error Resume Next
    LoopedCycleTime = 50    
    WaitUntil_SelectionChange = False
    'msgbox EVENT_CELL_CHANGE 
    select case EventType
        Case EVENT_CELL_CHANGE
            Set CheckVal = O.Selection
            Do
                Set CheckVal = O.Selection
                Val= CheckVal.Value
                Do 
                    WScript.Sleep LoopedCycleTime
                Loop Until O.Selection.Address <> CheckVal.Address
            Loop While CheckVal.Value = Val
            Set RtnVar = CheckVal
        Case EVENT_SELECTED_CELL_CHANGE 
            Do 
                WScript.Sleep LoopedCycleTime
            Loop Until O.Selection.Address <> CheckVal.Address
        Case EVENT_SELECTED_SHEET_CHANGE 
            Do 
                WScript.Sleep LoopedCycleTime
            Loop Until O.Selection.Worksheet.Name <> CheckVal.Worksheet.Name

        Case EVENT_SELECTED_WORKBOOK_CHANGE 
            Do 
                WScript.Sleep LoopedCycleTime
            Loop Until O.Selection.Worksheet.Parent.Name <> CheckVal.Worksheet.Parent.Name
    End Select
    'WaitUntil_Event = True
    'Include RunVBScript_FileName

End Sub

'/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'///////////////////////////////////////////////End of Main Sub Program//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```